# Updating android ui with timer

Tags: java, android, user-interface, timer

i am new to android programming, i searched through all the answers about this topic but still i am not able to implement what i want to do. My problem is: i want to update the picture at imageview with another picture in given periods. The imageview is needed to be updated with different pictures every time, total of 15-20 times. Here is what i have done so far but it is not working at all.

```
public class IlkMasal extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer sound;
    private Handler m_handler;
    private ImageView image;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firsttale);
        m_handler = new Handler();


    Button menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Button startbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music4);
    sound.start();
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture2);

    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_statusChecker);
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, 2000);
        }
    });

    menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent main= new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            startActivity(main);
        }  
    });

    }

    Runnable m_statusChecker = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run(){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture3);
            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_statusChecker);
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_statusChecker, 2000);
        }
    };
}
```

After i click startbutton i want to update the ui with different pictures every time. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: you can set one answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Yo can set  this runnable to run on your onClic and you will still need a method to get the next picture you want to show.

```
final int delay = 5000;
final int period = 1000;
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    image.setImageResource(getNextPicture());
    postDelayed(this, period);
   }
 };

postDelayed(r, delay);
```

Regards.

Comment: Why the -1? without comment? it will be better to know if im mistaken in something :)

Answer (score 0):

use [runOnUiThread](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html&ei=szH9T4fjNIS0rAfQvLzUBg&usg=AFQjCNEVbcf_xF52Np66Qp881y0W1JzaTQ&sig2=nHaF1VjehSyFKKfeGTaCkA) for Updating UI Elements from NON Ui Thread as:

```
    Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.picture3); //Update UI elements here
     }
    });
```